# Deleted Ruby (from /usr/bin/ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Okay, I did the stupidest thing possible. I was trying to upgrade from 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 and deleted `/usr/bin/ruby` along with `/usr/bin/ruby1.8.7` using the `rm -rf` command.

Now I am trying to install Ruby again with `sudo apt-get install ruby`, which gave loads of errors.

I then tried `sudo ruby setup.rb` which gave the error `sudo: ruby: command not found`, obviously.

1. I deleted `/usr/bin/ruby` along with the 1.8.7 version
2. I then ran the `rvm install 1.9.2` command to upgrade
3. Checked Ruby version with `ruby -v` and got this error:

   ```
   The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
    * ruby1.8
    * ruby1.9.1
   Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
   ```
4. With `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1`, I got lots of errors:

   ```
   Errors were encountered while processing:
    dictionaries-common
    aspell-en
    hunspell-en-ca
    hunspell-en-us
    ispell
    ienglish-common
    iamerican
    myspell-en-au
    myspell-en-gb
    myspell-en-za
   ```
5. Just to check whether Ruby was actually installed, I ran the setup, `sudo ruby setup.rb` which gave `sudo: ruby: command not found`.
6. I checked the locations where Ruby, if installed, was present and got the following results:

   ```
   /usr/lib/ruby 
   /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
   ```

Any idea on how to install Ruby successfully?

Comment: Obligatory comment: "You make backups, right?" ;)

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove "ruby*"`.

Comment: omg, thank you whirlwin, this worked.. i then reinstalled ruby and now its back to the 1.8.7 version again!

Comment: @berkes.. thanks for rubbing salt on my wounds.. unfortunately i didnt backup, lesson learnt!

Comment: @NineHourz, accept whirlwin's answer as Accepted then.

Answer (score 1):

Do this,

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby   # removes the package
sudo apt-get purge ruby    # deletes the package files
sudo apt-get install ruby  # install it again
```

Comment: I tried this, didn't work, got the same errors as mentioned above in 4)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to completely remove everything named ruby* with `sudo apt-get remove "ruby*"`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what kind of errors you're receiving? That might give you (and us) some sort of idea of what things you're missing, problems that need to be fixed, etc.